# Нужна ли запятая перед "и"? И как ее объяснить?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте, как объяснить запятую перед (и нужна ли она?).

Вот сделаешь уроки, и я потом куплю тебе красивую куклу.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Нужна, сложносочиненное предложение. Две основы: "сделаешь" и "я куплю".